# Show tags in list for awarded badges

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, badges

I was browsing [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/22/great-question) looking for gems I could learn some stuff from.

In this list you can only see the title of the question, it would be nice to see the tags as well. In the titles shouldn't be the tags, which is good in my opinion, but then it's hard to find the questions that are interesting to you here.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of searching gems from the badge page, try to find them from our very powerful [advanced search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) option. Try this keyword:

```
[tag-name] is:q votes:100
```

E.g. (click on it)

[`[sql] is:q votes:100`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D%20is:q%20votes:100)

See our [advanced search tips](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching). Since we can search such gems from the search page we don't need to add tag names on each question on the badge page.

Comment: Ah, that's nice and I learned something new. Thanks!